# "The element 'X' has invalid child element 'Y'. List of possible elements expected: 'Z'."

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am a bit new here and learning XSD Schema. I have a function which uploaded XML file, first it upload the schema then when it upload XML file it throws this exception:

`"The element 'X' has invalid child element 'Y'. List of possible elements expected: 'Z'."`

This is my XSD file:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="survey">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="***"/>
        <xs:element name="questions">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="X" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                       <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="option" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="***" use="optional"/>
                                </xs:extension>
                              </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Y" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Z">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="***" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                  <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                      <xs:extension base="xs:byte">
                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="***" use="optional"/>
                                      </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                  </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="***" use="optional"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="***" use="optional"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Z" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="***">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I have read similar posts, some are suggesting to change `<xs:sequence>` to `<xs:all>`; I have done this but is not working. Other are suggesting to add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` attribute  in root element ` but it is also not working.

I am still not understanding what is the real problem.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Ok I got my solution 

Just Put maxOccurs="unbounded in this line :

    <xs:element name="Subquestion" maxOccurs="unbounded">

Comment: If you found a solution post it as an answer :).

Comment: there is msg coming ..that you don't have reputation to post our own answer

Answer (score 0):

At least you've got an error in your XSD:

The closing "" just before declaring the "Y" element is not correct. 
Remove it and my guess is that it would work.

```
<xs:element name="X" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="option" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                              <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="***" use="optional"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                          </xs:simpleContent>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element> <------- REMOVE THIS
                <xs:element name="Y" minOccurs="0">
```